# How to define a custom cost function for Pulp library

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I am trying to use a custom cost function for using the PuLP Python library(https://realpython.com/linear-programming-python/). However I am not sure how to use extract my optimization variables. The objective function has a model I am trying to tune that has both integer and continues parameters

```py
def opt_funct(bins, reg):
    return some_calcuation(bins, reg) #returns some integer


model = pulp.LpProblem(name="small-problem", sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
bins = pulp.LpVariable(name="bins", lowBound=1, upBound=100, cat='Integer')
reg = pulp.LpVariable(name="reg", lowBound=0.0001, upBound=1.0, cat='Continues')
model += opt_funct(bins, reg)
status = model.solve()

The problem seems to be that variables are in some PuLP variable format. How can I use the variables for my own functions?
```

Comment: `pulp` does not work like that.  Your objective function needs to be a valid expression.  All `pulp` is doing is constructing a math model and handing it to a solver, so you cannot abstract away the obj function into something that spits out a number.  If you can express your obj mathematically as a function of the variables and constants in a linear expression, just do that and return the whole expression.

Comment: @AirSquid and if I cannot do that is there another library that I use? I am trying to tune a model that I need to first solve using the parameters. Then see how well it did based on the inertial cost my objects calculates.

Comment: I believe that `scipy.minimize` can chew on arbitrary functions.  Take a look at that and search this site for examples.  If you can express your obj in some mathematical formulation (even if it is non-linear) there are other solvers & frameworks that work on non-linear systems.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, to calculate my cost I have to build a rather complex model. Thank you for the help!